# LinQ with Count and Where condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hihi, I have a table with the following data:

```
    SampleID | SampleKey | SampleData
    1        | 1         | abc
    1        | 2         | def
    2        | 1         | xxx
    2        | 3         | yyy
    3        | 3         | zzz
    3        | 4         | qqq
```

I would like to retrieve all rows with at least one SampleKey as 3, which should give me

```
    2        | 1         | xxx
    2        | 3         | yyy
    3        | 3         | zzz
    3        | 4         | qqq
```

both SampleID with 2 and 3 should be returned as they are considered as one pair.

Pls advice how can I achieve this? May thanks!

Comment: oooppss, yes:
        2        | 1         | xxx
the above should be included as well!! Both SampleID with 3 and 2 should be returned...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not using `Contains`, but the built-in `Join` method for performance reasons..

```
var keys = source.Where(s => s.SampleKey == 3).Select(s => s.SampleID).Distinct();
var result = source.Join(keys, s => s.SampleID, k => k, (s, k) => s);
```

Comment: @nappy: I was worried when I saw it being deleted. +1, this is a great solution and gets the results desired.

Comment: I temporarily deleted it, because I forgot the Distinct/HashSet.

Comment: Nappy, what is the usage of the HashSet?

Comment: @steven-kik: You can translate it to `.Distinct()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is my final result:
        var c1 = source.Where(x => x.SampleKey == Mykey);
        var c2 = source.Join(c1, x => x.SampleID, x => x.SampleID, (i, o) => i);

Comment: @steven-kik: The result will not be correct, if you put in dublicate keys. Add another `{ SampleID = 2, SampleKey = 3, SampleData ="yyy" }` to your test data, and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but here's my bid:

```
var results = from r in MyTable
              where r.SampleID == 3 || r.SampleKey == 3
              select r;
var nResults = results.Count();
```

<strike>Though, I'll be honest, I don't know why your column named ID isn't actually an ID.</strike> Never mind, I think I get it now. You're linking the two columns as a unique key (or so I hope).

--

**EDIT**

[Nappy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395148/nappy) actually had a [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872053/linq-with-count-and-where-condition/5872272#5872272), and I'm not sure why s/he deleted it. Grabbing all rows with a 3 then rejoining them works perfect.

Comment: The SampleID isn't unique, because I have another unique key, I did not mention it, just to keep it simple.

but I don't quite get your suggestion, the last statement return the count, but I need the result set. :)

Comment: @StevenKik: Your question title included "Count" so I supplied it, but the "results" should have what you need. Though I'm not 100% sure I understand the problem any more (especially after your comment on the question itself about the `2,1,xxx` row matching)

Comment: 2,1,xxx should match, because this row with 2,3,yyy (matched the criteria of SampleKey == 3) are having the same SampleID, and there are considered as one pair of data.

Comment: yeap, I have used Nappy's suggestion, and it works like a charm, and now I back to the forum, I couldn't find his post...

Answer (score 1):

In the non-SQL-like syntax you could use

```
var groupsById = MyData.GroupBy(x => x.SampleId);
var groupsThatMatch = groupsById.Where(g => g.Any(x => x.SampleKey == 3));
var allRows = groupsThatMatch.SelectMany(g => g);
```

i.e group by ID, find the groups that match then flatten those back into rows. I don't know the SQL-like syntax, sorry.

Comment: @Rup: Wouldn't that exempt the whole list of rows with the ID column having 3 (but the Key column not being 3?) Or am I half awake this afternoon... (last row in OP's example with second column having a 4)

Comment: @Brad I don't think so: you'd end up with groupsById having three records with Key=1,2,3 (where Key = SampleId) with two rows each; then the groups with Key=2 and 3 would pass the second line, i.e. it'd return the whole group where Key=3, including both the SampleKey=3 and SampleKey=4 records. But that was all thought-compiled, maybe I did make a mistake.

Comment: I couldn't use the suggestion MyData.Group.

Comment: its `GroupBy` instead of `Group`

Comment: @jeroenh D'oh, yes, sorry - fixed.

Comment: @Rup: Any returns an Boolean. Your second line must be: `var groupsThatMatch = groupsById.Where(g => g.Any(x => x.SampleKey == 3));`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var idsToSelect = from x in MyTable where x.SampleKey == 3 select x.SampleID;       
 var results = from x in MyTable where idsToSelect.Contains(x.SampleID) select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("SampleID", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("SampleKey", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("SampleData", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, 1, "abc");
    dt.Rows.Add(1, 2, "def");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, 1, "xxx");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, 3, "yyy");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, 3, "zzz");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, 4, "qqq");

    var result = from DataRow myRow in dt.Rows  
                 where (int)myRow["SampleID"] == 3 || (int)myRow["SampleKey"] == 3
                 select myRow;
```

Comment: Sorry, I have just amended my original question, I did a mistake there, there should be a total of 4 rows in the resut:     
    2        | 1         | xxx
    2        | 3         | yyy
    3        | 3         | zzz
    3        | 4         | qqq

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do with:

```
var result = data.Where(
    y => data.Where(x => x.SampleKey == 3)
             .Select(x => x.SampleID)
             .Contains(y.SampleID));
```

Comment: why cross join the full data set? this is crazy.